# how to hide persistent_bottom_nav_bar 5.0.2 for specific screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have AboutStore() screen and i hided bottom nav bar when i was navigating to AboutStore() using this code below

this is from screen1() to AboutStore

```
pushNewScreen(
    context,
     screen: AboutStore(),
     withNavBar:
     false, 
     pageTransitionAnimation:
     PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
      );
```

and when i navigate to about store the bottom nav bar is hidded that is what i want but the problem is i have aslo button inside about store which navigates and other screen so i want to show bottom navigation to new screen, how to do that i use

```
withNavBar:
     true ,
```

this is from AboutStore() to HomeMenues(0), i want to show bottom nav bar this HomeMenues(0) screen

```
 pushNewScreen(
        context,
       screen: HomeMenues(0),
       withNavBar:
       true, 
    pageTransitionAnimation:                                          
     PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
                                        );
```

but it dosn't work